# Get difference between two days as a number in bash Linux

Tags: linux, bash, date

I need to get an integer that consists of the difference between two dates, so that I can then start a loop on this number. It works for date that grater then 10, but if date < 10, I got an error.

```sh
FROM_DAY=01
TO_DAY=08
counter=$((TO_DAY - FROM_DAY))
# I got this error:
# line 3: 08: value too great for base (error token is "08")
```

How do I get an integer from two dates correctly?

Comment: A leading 0 means it's an octal, base-8 number which only has digits 0 through 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In shell, an unquoted value with starting `0` is considered an octal value and `08` is an invalid octal number.

However, you may use this expression to do arithmetic using `base=10`:

```sh
counter=$((10#$TO_DAY - 10#$FROM_DAY))
echo "$counter" 
7
```